# How to refresh amazon s3 presigned URL after it reaches it expiration time using spring boot?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, token

Java code which can check whether the **presigned url** of file is expire or not. And if it gets expires again refresh add a new expiration time.

Comment: Check the `X-Amz-Date` and `X-Amz-Expires` parameters of the url and if the url is expired according to them create a new presigned url, you cannot "refresh" the original one.

Comment: Okayy. Thanks for help

Comment: @luk2302  Which is the safest get url method of s3 . So that malicitious user cant access my file url of s3.

Comment: the url does not matter, as long as the bucket is not public and you do not mess up the access permissions you are fine, end of story.

Comment: @luk2302 : how to extract value from X-Amz-Date. Other than using splitting the string.

Comment: no way. you need to split the string or use some url parser which internally splits the stsring.

Comment: @luk2302: Okay Thanks!